# VBA Copy and paste values in one cell based on value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

in this picture, the data in column I and R are both formulas. I want to write a code to have the formula in column I paste AS VALUES if there is an asterisk in the same row of column R and do nothin if it is blank. I need to do this for rows 9:44.

[image]

Comment: Where are you specifically stuck in writing this code?

Comment: I'm pretty new to VBA and haven't really written anything.

Comment: Ok, so what research have you done? Please note that SO is not really a code-writing service. It does have lots of related threads about pasting values tho. And maybe about looping too.

Comment: I see. I have done a bunch of Google searches and haven't come up with anyone with the exact problem. I've seen some which paste as values but can't get it to write off another cell. I'm wondering if I could do something like =IF(R9 = "*", Copy value in I9 and paste as values, do nothing). I'm just not familiar with writing that in VBA or looping. Below is the code written before I took over use of this tool. It is looing for a formula in CWIP% (Column I) and, if it is a formula then it does a multiplication. I don't want it to multiply certain rows which is why I need them as values.

Comment: Ok, so to start with a loop: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in Range("R9:R44")`, `Next cell`.